# How can I access a container on the host network with a bridged container?

Tags: docker, prometheus

I have a container which listens to all interfaces(0.0.0.0) on port 6060, it operates on the host network using the `network_mode: host` rule.
When I try to access it using Prometheus with this config:

```
  - job_name: 'server'
    metrics_path: /debug/metrics/prometheus
    static_configs:
         - targets: ['server:6060']
```

I get a "context deadline exceeded" error in Prometheus logs, which isn't really saying much.

I've tried `extra_hosts: - server:host-gateway` in the compose file with no avail.

Only when I do the same but with no host networking and only bridge networks it works fine, but I want to leave it on due to performance issues.

Is there any workaround or solution for this?

Comment: Did you expose the container's port `6060` to the host? i.e. in your compose for it, `ports: - 6060:6060`

Comment: @J.ScottElblein It operates on the host network using the `network_mode: host` rule, so it should be exposed by default no?

Comment: I dunno, i never use host mode, but can't hurt to try. 